# Mule string message split and aggreate

Tags: split, mule, aggregator

My requirement is accept a endpoint like localhost:8080/book/{id}/detail?name=whatever; then get the path param'id' and query param 'name'; then split message to create two requests like xxx1/id and xxx2/name; then aggregate the two responses together.

My initial idea is to use string like "id,name" then split to id and name for each request. I see many mule concepts splitter,router,vm,aggregator.. Can you please lighten me an solution to implement this ? What mule component I should use and what kind of customize java code Ineed to write.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can do is to get the value from your path param **id** and query param **name**.
If you are using Mule 3.6 or above version, you can get both the values using [MEL](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL), something like `#[message.inboundProperties.'http.uri.params'.id]` and `#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.name]`
reference :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/HTTP+Listener+Connector

Once you get the values, you can easily create the String you want.
For aggregating the response, you can either use Mule's available aggregator or can create your own custom aggregator using Java class

Comment: Hi Anirban,thanks for your reply.
Now I'm able to create the string, but I don't know how to split to two request and how to aggregate. Can you please tell me which Mule component I should use?

Comment: You need to fire 2 separate requests and then maybe use flow variables to store the responses from these requests and write some custom "aggregation" logic